# How can we change the color of the callout that comes when we press a pin in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview, mkannotationview

The callout that is being displayed when we press an MKAnnotationPin can be customised to have image, title and also subtitle. Is it possible to change the blackcolor of the callout to some other color, say brown?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a custom annotation view to do that. There is not a way to specify the color with the default annotation style.

Answer (score 0):

MKAnnotationPin comes in three colors Red, Green and Purple. You will need to replace the selected Map Annotation Pin object with a new one.

edit:wrong answer, I miss read the question. I don't think you can change the callout background color. You need to create a custom UIView for the callout

Comment: This wasn't about the pin color.